# Target the body of html loaded into div

Tags: jquery, html, css, load

I am loading html pages into a div using jQuery. How can I target the body of the html pages to apply margin using jquery/css? I can do it manually on each html page but I was looking for a quicker way.

My attempt(which isn't working):

```
$myDiv= $targetDiv.find("#targetContent");
$myDiv.load($(this).attr('href'));
$myDiv.find("body").css("margin-top","50px");
```

link:

Comment: $myDiv.parent("body").css("margin-top","50px"); ?

Comment: It's not valid HTML to have `<body>` tags inside `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be only **one** body element in the whole document. However you can use `iframe`'s.

```
$myDiv = $targetDiv.find("#targetContent"); //assuming that #targetContent is an iframe
$myDiv.attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
$($myDiv.get(0).contentWindow.document.body).css("margin-top","50px");
```

Remember that you can access iframe's content **only** if its src is from the same domain.

**EDIT**:

I figured out that `jQuery.load` function trims the `body` and `head` tags from the loaded HTML so changing body margin gives you nothing. All you have to do is expand padding of the container element

```
$myDiv= $targetDiv.find("#targetContent");
$myDiv.load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
    $myDiv.css("padding-top","+=50px");
});
```

**EDIT 2**:

If you want to access the first `div` loaded by jQuery you have to do

```
$myDiv.children('div').first().css("padding-top","+=50px");
```

But if you want the solution more close to your question you can add another `div` in your `#targetContent` and add the padding to it. I assume that `#targetContent` contains some more elements. The above approach should resolve your problem.

Comment: I don't want to use an iframe for this project.

Comment: Then you simply **can't** have more than one `body`. All you can do here is modify the file you're trying to load that you replace `<body>` tag with some `div` or something.

Comment: I can add the margin on the body of each html but as I said I was looking for a faster way to do it. I could place everything in a div and add margin on that, for example but I was looking for a method that would allow me to do it without editing the html pages(that's why I thought adding the margin on the body would be possible)

Comment: Does your jQuery actually load the desired HTML?

Comment: Yes it does work, but it applies padding on the whole container div. I want to apply the padding on the inner html of the pages that load inside that container. (That's why I was trying body)

Comment: It is not possible because as I said before, jQuery removes the `body` tag from the loaded HTML.

Comment: Yeah, so can't we use a different method? Since on all the content of my html pages are inside a div I tried using `#container div:first-child{padding-top:110px}` but it didn't work.

Comment: Add an example how your typical html page looks like. We can discuss this on and on forever.

Comment: That doesn't work, although I found that adding the css after the content is loaded works: `$myDiv.css("margin-top","110px");` I would like to try your approach as well though, are you sure the code is correct?

Comment: I updated it a bit. Notice that I wraped the padding change (last line) in a function which is the second parameter of `.load`. It means it will be done after the content is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have the body inside of a div. body is the parent of all elements in the html page. You might want `.parent()`

```
$myDiv.parent("body").css("margin-top","50px");
```

Comment: Apparently the user is trying to get the body of another HTML loaded using Jquery.load

Comment: @HusseinNazzal - absolutely. OP - you need to set $myDiv properly.

Comment: Edited my post, does that help? It's not necessary to add the margin on the body if it's not possible. Maybe we can use something like first-child pseudo element?

Comment: @zefs - what is $targetDiv? can you make a jsfiddle example for us?